# Class member as an event handler for a C-style event in C++

Tags: c++, event-handling

I'm working with the Android NDK. Their we have the main method like:

```
void android_main(struct android_app *app)
{
    // onAppCmd is the event:
    app->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
}
```

The definition of `engine_handle_cmd` is:

```
static void engine_handle_cmd(struct android_app *app, int32_t cmd)
{
    // Event handling code here...
}
```

Instead of using a static method like above, I would like to create a singleton event manager class and use that to handle the `onAppCmd` event like below:

The declaration of the event manager:

```
#pragma once

class EventManager
{
public:
   static EventManager &getInstance();
   void handleCommand(struct android_app *app, int32_t cmd);
   ~EventManager();
private:
   EventManager();
   EventManager(EventManager const&);
   void operator=(EventManager const&);
};
```

Then the class definition:

```
#include "EventManager.h"

EventManager &EventManager::getInstance()
{
   static EventManager instance;
   return instance;
}

EventManager::~EventManager() {}

EventManager::EventManager() {}

void EventManager::operator=(EventManager const &) {}

void EventManager::handleCommand(struct android_app *app, int32_t cmd)
{
   // Event handling code...
}
```

Now, when I try in my method:

```
void android_main(struct android_app *app)
{
    EventManager &manager = EventManager::getInstance();
    app->onAppCmd = manager.handleCommand();
}
```

I get the compiler error:

```
reference to non-static member function must be called.
```

If I try the below:

```
void android_main(struct android_app *app)
{
    EventManager &manager = EventManager::getInstance();
    app->onAppCmd = &manager.handleCommand();
}
```

I get the compiler error:

`cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function`.

Is there anyway I can get this approach to work without making the method `static`? Any suggestions for bets practices on event handler classes are also appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need a static method or other free function at some point because it is not possible to invoke member functions from C. Typically there should be a way to pass a pointer to object instance somehow to invoke member function.

Comment: @AlexF Oh, that's a clever idea :) Yeah, I think I will do that! I will accept that as the answer if you can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you will have to use static/free function/lambda. But that's it, all the rest can be done, in different ways, using objects. For example, you can use your singleton inside of this function:

```
void callback_wrapper1(struct android_app *app, int32_t cmd)
{
    EventManager &manager = EventManager::getInstance();
    // do singleton stuff here
}

void android_main(struct android_app *app)
{
    app->onAppCmd = &callback_wrapper1;
}
```

If you don't like your singleton in the callback, you can also use dedicated field from `android_app` to pass generic data to callback:

```
void callback_wrapper2(struct android_app *app, int32_t cmd)
{
    EventManager &manager = *static_cast<EventManager*>(app->userData);
    // do what you want here
}

void android_main(struct android_app *app)
{
    app->userData = static_cast<void *>(&EventManager::getInstance());
    app->onAppCmd = &callback_wrapper2;
}
```